# SharePoint 2010 Announcements upload

Tags: announcements

HI i have created a announcements list in SharePoint 2010 and when I try to add new item and select body we have upload file and add image options in the ribbon as shown in fig1, when i try to click them it is throwing correlation errors as shown in the fig2 below . I have added the log file i found after merging all servers logs

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
07/20/2017 09:28:45.62  w3wp.exe (PDPRSPPIIS03:0x0430)              0x1B1C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:https://somesite.com:443/Plan/PC/_layouts/RteUploadDialog.aspx?LCID=1033&Dialog=UploadDocument&UseDivDialog=true&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsomesite%2Epadot%2Ecom%2FPlanning%2FProgramCenter%2FLists%2FVinod%2FNewForm%2Easpx%3FRootFolder%3D%26IsDlg%3D1&seed=0.5082869080853651&IsDlg=1) 772d8593-ee07-42e2-9c02-b4ecb8af4578
07/20/2017 09:28:45.65  w3wp.exe (PDPRSPPIIS03:0x0430)              0x1B1C  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/  772d8593-ee07-42e2-9c02-b4ecb8af4578
07/20/2017 09:28:45.73  w3wp.exe (PDPRSPPIIS03:0x0430)              0x1B1C  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)     at System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RteUploadDialogPage.OnLoad(EventArgs args)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  772d8593-ee07-42e2-9c02-b4ecb8af4578
07/20/2017 09:28:45.73  w3wp.exe (PDPRSPPIIS03:0x0430)              0x1B1C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:https://somesite.com:443/Plan/PC/_layouts/RteUploadDialog.aspx?LCID=1033&Dialog=UploadDocument&UseDivDialog=true&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsomesite%2Edot%2Ecom%2FPlan%2FPC%2FLists%2FVin%2FNewForm%2Easpx%3FRootFolder%3D%26IsDlg%3D1&seed=0.5082869080853651&IsDlg=1)). Execution Time=104.522222796473  772d8593-ee07-42e2-9c02-b4ecb8af4578
```

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62549/discussion-on-question-by-splearner-sharepoint-2010-announcements-upload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the cause for it and resolved. I have seen two libraries with the same name and that is the reason the uls logs showing " An entry with the same key already exists." . I have deleted one of the library and every thing working normally. But SP ULS logs should have been more appropriate and accurate to show which library or list was duplicated. Since it took time for me to figure out what is causing the issue.